# 1..1 and 1..n cardinalities on the same relationship

Tags: database-design, schema

I have two tables (`companies` and `users`), for which the following rules apply:

- A **User** has a **Role** ('employee' and 'boss')
- There is one and only one 'boss' in a **Company**.
- A **User** can be in only one **Company**.

Before thinking about the **Boss** case, I created only two tables and added a foreign key column `company_id` on the `users` table. So every **User** has a **Company** and everything is alright.

But now, there is a new rule: *there can be only one boss*. How do I write this rule in my schema?

- Should I create a `boss_id` column in `companies` table? If so, should I leave the `company_id` NULL for this kind of **User**? (but it seems weird) Or should I add `company_id` and `boss_id` in both tables? (but it's redundant).
- Should I keep going with only `company_id` and keep the rule in my head ("hey, remember, the schema does not tell anything about this, but you can't create two bosses for the same **Company**").
- Should I... Hum, I must be tired I forgot the other patterns?

I think I missed something really simple, but I can't figure it!

---

*This is an over-simplifed example, one could say there can be multiple bosses.*

Answer (score 2):

In your requirement *employee* means *not boss*, so this should work fine.

```
-- Company (CompanyID) exists
--
Company {CompanyID}
     PK {CompanyID}

-- User (UserID) works for company (CompanyID)
--
User {UserID, CompanyID}
  PK {UserID}
  SK {UserID, CompanyID} -- superkey (unique), needed for FK ..

 FK1 {CompanyID} REFERENCES Company


-- User (UserID) is boss in company (CompanyID)
--
CompanyBoss {UserID, CompanyID}
         PK {CompanyID} 
        FK1 {UserID, CompanyID} REFERENCES User
```

Note: all attributes NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

In most schemas, roles are defined in a separate table, and there is a table `userroles` which contains information about the role**s** (note the plural) a user has. You should consider adopting this scheme, because it will be more flexible for future developments.

---

However, when you're set on sticking to the tables you already have, you basically have two options (which are not exclusive):

1. adding a `boss_id` column to the `companies` table, what you already mentioned. To check if a user is a boss, you need to join the `users` table with the `companies` table, on `companies.boss_id = users.id`. Depending on the number of users, it might be worthwhile to make an index for the `boss_id` column.
2. adding an `is_boss` boolean column to the `users` table. To check whether a user can be assigned to the boss role in a company, just check if there's another user with a matching `company_id` and `is_boss = true`. Again, depending on the number of users, it might be worthwhile to make an index on `company_id` and `is_boss`.

Without knowing further details about your application, it's hard to say which is the best of the two. Implementing both will be more work, but better from a performance perspective.